# how to handle login with facebook and goolgle from mobile with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working on mobile application with laravel,

and the app have login with facebook and google

and the mobile guy will deal with it throw firebase

i need to know how to deal with it as a back end , because it's new to me.
this is my customer table

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->text('address');
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->date('birthday');
            $table->timestamps();
```

thanks.

Comment: take a look of laravel Socialite

Comment: thanks but the mobile will handle this with firebase .